# Bootstrap´s 4 Checkbox on Angular 4

Tags: html, angular, typescript, bootstrap-4

I´m trying to display content if an user click on a checkbox, using ngModel and ngIf directives. But it doesn´t works.

```
  <div class="custom-control custom-checkbox">
    <input type="checkbox" class="custom-control-input" id="customCheck1"  name="Situacion" [(ngModel)]="Paso1.Acepta">
    <label class="custom-control-label" for="customCheck1">Check this custom checkbox</label>
  </div>

  <div *ngIf="Paso1.Acepta == 'true'">
    <p>...</p>
  </div
```

And in my TS i have this object

```
  Paso1:Object={
  Municipio: null,
  Provincia: null,
  CCAA: null,
  Longitud: null,
  Anchura: null,
  Acepta: true,
  }
```

What i'm doing wrong?

Comment: So, does `<div *ngIf="Paso1.Acepta">` work? If not, you maybe should provide a fiddle/plunkr...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`Paso1.Acepta` is a boolean variable, but you're comparing it to the string `'true'` in your `ngIf` condition.

Change your condition to simply `"Paso1.Acepta"` to check for a truthy value:

```
<div *ngIf="Paso1.Acepta">
    <p>...</p>
</div>
```

To explicitly check for the boolean true value, use strict equality and drop the quotes:

```
<div *ngIf="Paso1.Acepta === true">
```

Comment: This is more accurate

Answer (score 0):

Without comparing just add the variable.

```
 <div class="custom-control custom-checkbox">
    <input type="checkbox" class="custom-control-input" id="customCheck1"  name="Situacion" [(ngModel)]="Paso1.Acepta">
    <label class="custom-control-label" for="customCheck1">Check this custom checkbox</label>
  </div>

  <div *ngIf="Paso1.Acepta">
    <p>...</p>
  </div>
```